# Парсер для верстки EMail письма

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email, рассылка

Доброго всем времени суток.

Стала задача написать утилиту для рассылки писем. С самой утилитой вобщем то проблем нет. Есть проблемы с версткой писем.

Как известно, HTML верстка самого письма - вещь не тривиальная, так как она отличается от обычной HTML верстки обычных страниц в части поддержки различных фич.

Самая большая проблема, это отсутствие поддержки `<style>` в `<head>` для GMail (подробнее [тут](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)). Т.е. как вы понимаете, нельзя набросать общие CSS стили для элементов по селекторам. Эти стили нужно прописывать к каждому элементу через атрибут `style=""`.

Очень здорово эта задача решается у [mailchimp.com](http://mailchimp.com). У них есть встроенный парсер, который парсит тег `<style>` и вешает стили к соответствующим элементам. Т.е. вот такое письмо:

```
...
<style>
a { color: green; }
a.someLink { color: red; }
</style>
...
<body>
...
<a class="someLink">first</a>
<a class="anotherClass">second</a>
<a>third</a>
...
```

Преобразуется к виду:

```
...
<style>
a { color: green; }
a.someLink { color: red; }
</style>
...
<body>
...
<a class="someLink" style="color: red;">first</a>
<a class="anotherClass" style="color: green;">second</a>
<a style="color: green;">third</a>
...
```

Это очень круто, и это то чего надо бы нам добиться. Суть в том что у письма есть стилизованный шаблон и предполагается что его контентная письма редактируется с помощью WYSIWYG редактора. Т.е. контент у письма получается в виде HTML, но из за отсутствии поддержки тега `<style>`, контент не форматируется в соответствии со стилем самого шаблона.

Самый идеальный вариант это найти какой то инструмент с помощью которого можно было бы делать то же самое что делает mailchimp. Т.е. какой то парсер DOM и CSS, который отдает DOM с навешанными стилями. Может кто знает про что то похожее?

PS: в идеале бы конечно на PHP :)

Comment: Python не годится от слова совсем ?

Comment: @gecube почему же? Годится. PHP - было бы идеально, так как проект написан на нем, но подключить я могу все что угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инструментами, которые предлагает [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/zurb-stack.html).
Там есть и [шаблонизатор](https://github.com/zurb/inky), который позволяет писать меньше кода (например, колоночная система, которая из одного тега автоматически разворачивается в фарш из таблиц), и [инлайнер](https://github.com/zurb/inline-css) (то, о чём вы спрашиваете).

Они поставляются в виде npm-пакетов, но никто не мешает вам установить их и вызывать из своего кода на php. На чём написаны сами инструменты, по идее, вам должно быть неважно.

Comment: Вы мой спаситель, благодарю. Да, мне, в принципе, без разницы на каком языке написан инструмент. Подключить я смогу все что угодно :)